# Минимальный и максимальный элемент массива в C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Массивы данных содержат значения роста для девочек и мальчиков. Определить, кто(мальчик или девочка) самый высокий и самый маленький.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это просто просьба выполнить учебное задание без малейших попыток что-то сделать самостоятельно

Answer (score 3):

Поиск максимального элемента:

```
int m[5] = {1, -1, 0, 4, 2};
int max = m[0];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    if(m[i] > max)
    {
        max = m[i];
    }
}
```

Поиск минимального:

```
int m[5] = {1, -1, 0, 4, 2};
int min = m[0];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    if(m[i] < min)
    {
        min = m[i];
    }
}
```

Вот вам алгоритмы, проверять в цикле каждый элемент в максимальным (минимальным), а если он больше (меньше) тогда меняем максимальный (минимальный) элемент. В гугле полно примеров, популярная начальная тема.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм `minmax_element` из STL вам поможет.